# How to perform a simple search on Dojo DataGrid

Tags: search, datagrid, dojo

For a project, I had to swictch from DataTable jquery plugin to Dojo.
Dojo is great and everything works fine !

But, I miss the dataTable's simple search form (http://datatables.net/).

I know that Dojo have the Filter plugin which could make that, but it's not simple, for the users, as the dataTable input field (at less two more click for a global search on a table :/).

I search all the web but i couldn't find an exemple with it :/

If someone has a clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what kind of backend data store you are using to power your grid.

It's usually just a simple matter of calling `grid.setQuery({name: "FooBar" , ignoreCase: true });`

But lets say you are using an `[AndOrReadStore][1]`, rather than a simple ItemFileReadStore, then you might specify the `columsToQuery` and the `columnValue` as well.

Remmber, you always query your *grid* not the store. The grid will pass the query on to the store.

So, to do what you want, just create a new input on your page. Capture key presses or onchange, and then query your grid accordingly. This will filter results that don't match.

The reason why you might use query, is because if your store is powered from the server, it will make sure to requery the backend.

However, if your grid is entirely loaded in memory, then you can do client side filtering by using `filter()`.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answer. I discover setFilter() who works fine.